# Socket.io log (client not handshaken client should reconnect)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

is anyone facing this problem too? My logfile is flooded with that message:

"client not handshaken client should reconnect" & "transport end".

It's hard for me to reconstruct, as it doesn't appear when i connect to my socket server with different browsers. But on live environment with different users, my log file size grows exponential :)

Anyone having this problem too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that this is just happening in xhr-polling mode on chrome v14. So I installed Chrome v16 dev and the problem is fixed.